# How can i fix this terminal error for lapack and fftw3f?

Tags: gcc

```
Checking for gcc [ok]
Extract gcc version 5.4 
Checking for OpenMP activation [disable]
Extract CPU architecture: 64 bits
Looking for specific library directories for 64 bits [ko]
Checking for lapack [ko]
Checking for blas [disable]
Checking for gslcblas [disable]
Checking for gsl [disable]
Checking for fftw3f [ko]
Configuration failed
```

Comment: It might be helpful to include what Ubuntu version you are using, what you are trying to do, and what command led to the error

Comment: ubuntu16.04 and am creating mex file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it seems that you need to install some development packages with headers:

```
sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev libfftw3-dev
```

I found this packages with search on https://packages.ubuntu.com.

Comment: Thank you for the information and i resolved the error